# Matlab - Can you combine 2 circular antenna arrays in one plot

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do this using both Antenna Toolbox and Phased Array toolbox. But it's not allowing me to have multiple circular arrays.

Is there any way to combine 2 circular Antenna arrays and plot the summation of their phase patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to plot more than 1 plot on the same axis in MATLAB:

```
hFigure = figure();
hAxes = axes();
set(hAxes, 'NextPlot', add); %<! New plot will be added instead of replacing
...
Plotting Code #001
...
Plotting Code #002
...
```

If you have a function which plots in a new figure and you want to merge 2 figures you should use the abilities to extract data from a figure.

IF the data is a Line based you can extract data using the `XData`, `YData` and `ZData` (See [Chart Line Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html)).
Start with the Axes handler to get its children handlers and extract the data.

Then just add it to the other figure as explained above.

Comment: Thank you Royi. I tried the above solution, using the NextPlot option, but because it's an Antenna Toolbox system, with specialised Pattern Analysis, the Objects it creates from Antennas are programmed with set parameters that some are not changeable. (not that I know of). And even if I force the Plot to show 2 Objects - The algorithms for Patterns in the Program will not recognise the merged antennas.

Comment: Unless there is a way around it, where the program allows for merging of 2 Antenna systems, and processes the Summation of their radiation accordingly.

Comment: Your question was about merging data from 2 figures. This will do that. If you want the function of those combined this is a different problem.

Comment: Thanks Royi and Ander for the Edit.